# How to stop mysqli bind_param auto casting either from PHP or MySql?

Tags: php, mysqli

I having a problem with the bind_param function for PHP 5.3.2.

Let say I have a database table name 'tbl_user' and data as below:

```
----------------------------------------
user_id [Int]  | user_name [varchar(15)]
----------------------------------------
350            | John Smitch
351            | Kelly Ann
----------------------------------------
```

**First Coding:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $v_user_id);
$v_user_id = '350a';
$stmt->execute();
```

System will return 1 result which user_id is 350 with the name 'John Smitch'.

**Second Coding:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $v_user_id);
$v_user_id = 'a350';
$stmt->execute();
```

System will return empty result to me.

So far I know that PHP 5.3 will auto cast the value to string and once MySql receive data from php will auto cast again to it own data type which define in the table structure.

**So how can I handle this situation so that system will return empty result to me when I pass value '350a'?**

Comment: your both code will never run,because `$v_stmt` is undefined.

Comment: Why would you want to input an invalid type into your SQL statement? Why not just use is_int() to determine if it is valid and if not, throw an error or otherwise gracefully handle the invalid type.

Comment: oops, $v_stmt should be $stmt

Comment: **A Jolly Geek**, thinking of that as well but wish to find a better solution first as currently I am writing the some basic framework for PHP and MySqli.

Comment: If, in MySQL console, `SELECT * from tbl WHERE user_id='350a'` returns result, I think you'll then have to do the validation work at PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the value before executing the statement. The simplest way to validate it would be to check if the string is numeric.

```
$v_user_id = '350a';
if(is_numeric($v_user_id)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $v_user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```